# eclipse 3.4 can't start

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, memory, eclipse-3.4

Yesterday, I try to start eclipse 3.4 by click eclipse.exe (in eclipse folder), and run normally.
Then yesterday night, I do windows update.  Today, when I try to run eclipse 3.4, it has error. The error message you can find at here [SCREENSHOT](http://punyaku.com/eclipse34_start_error.png)

I use windows xp sp2, and java 1.5 update 14.

I don't know how to fix that, so I uninstalled my jdk1.5.14 then installed jdk1.5.21.  The problem still exist.
If I use bat file (eclipse.bat) with the content of the file is like below:

*eclipse -vmargs -Xmx256M*

it will run normally.  But when I change into -Xmx512M or (>= 512M), it will display error like the screenshot.

The same problem is occurred when I start with eclipse 3.5.  But when I start with eclipse 3.3, eclipse 3.3 is start normally (I think eclipse 3.3 is use memory lower than 3.4 above, <= 512M only, have tested, but forgot how much memory consumed by eclipse 3.3).

I am just guess the problem is from my windows.  I really appreciate if anyone can help this problem.

Comment: Can you attach content of your eclipse.ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this [**eclipse.ini**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590):
it does have a Xmx lower than 512 and still manage to run eclipse pretty fast (I would recommend using the latest JDK for this, though, even if you are using JDK5 for your programs)

Check also each lines of your `eclipse.ini`: they must not have any extra space.

Comment: I have check eclipse.ini too... but it can't start too...

here is my configuration of eclipse.ini file
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-framework
plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.0.v20080605-1900.jar
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m


if i change -Xmx512m to -Xmx400m for example, yes it can start... but if 468 or above (default is 512 for eclipse 3.4), it can't start. i don't know if this problem is from java or my windows, because before I do windows update, it runs normally, but after windows update, the problem is occurred...

Comment: Hi VonC, after I try your eclipse.ini with content below

-showlocation
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-framework
plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.2.R34x_v20080826-1230.jar
-vm
jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms128m
-Xmx384m
-Xss2m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CompileThreshold=5
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote

it works!  But I'm just confused why the problem exist after windows update...

Comment: Hi VonC, after try again, there is 1 line that needed for my eclipse to run...

-XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Anyway it works! Thanks...

PS: i can use your config.ini as your post, but just wondering, i just download a clean eclipse 3.5 zip file into my notebook.  After I unzipped, and just click eclipse.exe, it is not worked, have to add "-XX:MaxPermSize=128m" in config.ini so it can start... (3.4 too), but I remember for sure, first time I run eclipse 3.4, doesn't need to add that line...

Comment: @Jef: thank you for those feedbacks. I will complete my tests to study why this `XX:MaxPermSize` (and its value) matter.

Comment: Hi VonC, maybe this link is helpful http://www.unixville.com/~moazam/stories/2004/05/17/maxpermsizeAndHowItRelatesToTheOverallHeap.html

Comment: @Jef: This shows conclusive proof that `PermSize` and `MaxPermSize` are additional to the `-Xmx` setting"... so if you put too much (between `Xmx`, `PermSize` and `MaxPermSize`), it appears to exceed some kind of limit, right?