# Eclipse and Android SDK stopped working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, motion

I have been programming using eclipse and the Android SDK for a while now, and they stopped working suddenly today. What happens is whenever I try to open them, either from the start menu or folder, the splash/loading screen comes onto the screen for about a second, and then disappears. This has never happened before, and I can't seem to find anyone online with a similar problem. I restarted my computer, re-installed both the SDK and Eclipse, and still no luck. The only thing that may be affecting it is that I recently installed the Leap Motion software and SDK 2 days ago, and I haven't used either Eclipse or the SDK since then.

I'm running windows 8 and I already installed a JRE when I first got this computer. Thanks for any help. I you want me to post any more information about the problems just tell me what and how to find it. Thanks for any help.

---

UPDATE

---

I tried to add -clean and the same thing happened, and the same thing happened when I ran eclipse.exe from command prompt. No error message came up.

---

SOLVED

---

I re-installed java, and now it works perfectly!
I think I may have messed up Java when I stopped an update in progress (which I forgot about until this morning. Sorry) Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Go to the command prompt, navigate to the Eclipse directory and run eclipse.exe from there. It should give you a useful error message on why it won't run. Post that here and someone can help.

Comment: Here's some [useful info](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) about specifying your JVM.

Comment: Start eclipse with -clean argument, might be a workspace screwup, that could help.

Comment: Here are a few related questions: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12426810/778118), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4419983/778118), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3591374/778118).

Comment: I have always had trouble running anything from command prompt. I just was never taught how to. I keep getting an error that it can't find the location specified, after multiple attempts. If anyone can give me some tips or point me to a website that could, it would really help. (I have already tried a few websites that didn't work)

Comment: First, right click your Eclipse icon, and add -clean in Target: box, e.g. as such: C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean. When things suddenly stop working after additional packages install its often a workspace issue and -clean would kill your old metafiles and allow them to be regenerated for new plugins.

Comment: Also make sure you are launching Eclipse using JDK 6, and not a JRE, and not JDK 7.

Comment: The question has been re-posted on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/q/630325/53590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

---

I re-installed java, and now it works perfectly! I think I may have messed up Java when I stopped an update in progress (which I forgot about until this morning. Sorry) Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the Android Studio, much better than Eclipse.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

And, for simulator, I recommend using Genymotion
http://www.genymotion.com/

much much faster than android simulador

Comment: This is also good advice, but it does nothing to answer the OP's question.