# Eclipse crashes

Tags: java, eclipse, crash

I am using 64 bit eclipse with 64 bit JVM.while swaping between windows my eclipse is getting crash at any random time (not every time).

here is my eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

.log file of my workspace has some log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2013-12-25 11:55:34.935
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2013-12-25 11:55:34.943
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2013-12-25 11:55:35.118
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2013-12-25 11:55:35.129
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2013-12-25 11:55:40.085
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2013-12-25 11:55:40.091
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
!SESSION 2013-12-25 12:09:31.862 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2013-12-25 12:09:36.494
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
```

is there any way i can trace why my eclipse is not running properly.Help me

Comment: Pratik, look this answer, may can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597862/eclipse-workspace-crashes-on-startup/42227615#42227615

Answer (score 0):

try passing this command to JVM `eclipse -vm C:\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe` this will force the JVM to run in a process different from that of Eclipse, 
as mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1805506/1951298

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
 <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>
```

in pom.xml fixed mine.